# How to compare private data fields of objects to ensure they are the same (Java)?

Tags: java, class, object, boolean

Just to start off here, this is homework/a lab and I'm looking for advice. I am developing a very small program that is essentially a counter with a min/max value constraint and a method that pushes the value up and another that rolls the value back to zero 0. So, the private data fields I have for my Counter class are:

```
private int minimum; 
private int maximum; 
private int currentValue;
```

The trouble I am having here is with a method that compares my Counter Class to another theoretical object based off the same class. In this case, we're looking to see that the data fields between the two objects are the same. I have researched several ways of doing this including using reflections and the famous EqualsBuilder, but am having trouble implementing each.

Here's the code that they've given me.

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    boolean result = true;
    if (otherObject instanceof Counter)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You simply compare the values of the instance variables, using equals for Objects, and '==' for primitives. Of course you'll first need to cast otherObject to an instance of your class.

Comment: Any methods in `Counter` can access the private variables of any `Counter` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your equals method is in the Counter class, it has access to all the private members of that class, even if they are members of a different instance of that class.

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    if (otherObject instanceof Counter)
    {
        Counter ocounter = (Counter) otherObject;
        if (this.minimum != ocounter.minimum)
            return false;
        ...
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: there is probably a mistake, `boolean result = false;` if the otherObject is not a instance of Counter the equals method should return false.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and to everyone else who provided an answer. I'm grateful for the assistance and will be sure to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the `equals`-method can be a real pain, especially if you have a lot of properties in your class.

The JavaDoc for the [equals-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) states

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

And, if you check the JavaDoc for the [hashCode-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Therefore, it is typically recommended that you implement both methods (`equals` and `hashCode`). The following shows one way of doing this that is based on the `java.util.Objects`-class that came with Java 7. The method [Objects.equals(Object, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) handles null checks which makes the code simpler and easier to read. Furthermore, the [hash-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-) is a convenient way of creating values that can be used with `hashCode`.

So, to answer your question. In order to access the attributes of your *other* object, simply perform a type cast. After that you can access the *other* object's private properties. But, remember to always do this after you have checked the type using *instanceof*.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Counter) { // Always check the type to be safe
        // Cast to a Counter-object
        final Counter c = (Counter) other;

        // Now, you can access the private properties of the other object
        return Objects.equals(minimum, c.minimum) &&
               Objects.equals(maximum, c.maximum) &&
               Objects.equals(currentValue, c.currentValue);
    }
    return false; // If it is not the same type, always return false
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(currentValue, maximum, minimum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `equals` is a method of `Counter`, you can access all the private fields of `Counter`, so you can do something like this:

```
if (otherObject instanceof Counter)
{
    if (this.minimum != ((Counter) otherObject).minimum) {
        result = false;
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class is called `Counter` and you created `getters` for all the private fields (that you should do):

```
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (other instanceof Counter) {
            Counter c= (Counter) other;
            result = (this.getMinimum() == that.getMinimum() &&
                     this.getMaximum() == that.getMaximum() &&
                     this.getCurrentValue() == that.getCurrentValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
```